# The name of a created PDF is not transferred from the server to the client (GWT - GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I develope a GWT-application which creates a PDF-file at the server, and then transferres it to the client.
At the client-side, a window appears which allows the user either to

- open it with a program assigned to the file name ending, or
- save it to disc.

I have read several threads to this topic, such as

- [How can a user download a file in client side (Google Web Toolkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725198/how-can-a-user-download-a-file-in-client-side-google-web-toolkit)
- [GWT: Showing PDF created as POST response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850823/gwt-showing-pdf-created-as-post-response)
- [How can a user download a file in client side (Google Web Toolkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725198/how-can-a-user-download-a-file-in-client-side-google-web-toolkit)

and that helped me coding the doGet()-methode in my print-servlet like this:

```
resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

This works fine when testing and debugging using the local GWT-developement server.

**But my big problem is:

After deploying to GAE and running the code on GAE, the created pdf-name is not transferred to the client...!**
Instead of e.g. *TestPdf-25072016.pdf*, the name only consists of the word *print*.

This leads to the fact that the standard-program for a PDF is not invoked automatically when I want to open it. And, of course, print is not the name of the PDF I want to have...

Where is my failure? Especially I am confused that everything works fine when using the local developement server?

Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the actual HTTP header sent to you when you call printing in GAE.
Maybe GAE is adjusting the header or just blocking it.